# Cambiar Columna por Fila al escribir Excel con Java

Tags: javascript, java

Intento cambiar una columna para ponerla como tema del resto de columnas, este es el código que tengo hasta el momento, el cual genera excel.

```
  while (res.next()) {
                Row filaDatos = sheet.createRow(numfilaDatos);
                for (int a = 0; a < numCol; a++) {
                    Cell celdaDatos = filaDatos.createCell(a);
                    celdaDatos.setCellStyle(datosEstilo);
                    if (a == 2) {
                        celdaDatos.setCellValue(res.getInt(a + 1));
                    } else {
                        celdaDatos.setCellValue(res.getString(a + 1));
                    }
                }
                numfilaDatos++;
            }
            if (option == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                if (fileChooser.getSelectedFile() != null) {
                    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileChooser.getSelectedFile() + ".xls");
                    book.write(out);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes poblar el excel de manera que ya venga en el formato que necesitas. Asi te evitas tener que cambiar columas luego:

Por ejemplo:

```
XSSFSheet spreadsheet = workbook.createSheet("EntregaRecepcion");

XSSFRow row = spreadsheet.createRow(1);
XSSFCell cell;
cell = row.createCell(1);
cell.setCellValue("Columna1");
cell = row.createCell(2);
cell.setCellValue("Columna2");



ps = con.prepareStatement("EXEC PA_ENTREGA " + quincena.getSelectedItem() + "," + ano.getSelectedItem());

res = ps.executeQuery();

int i = 2;
while(res.next()) {
    row = spreadsheet.createRow(i);
    cell = row.createCell(1);
    cell.setCellValue(res.getInt("datoColuma1"));
    cell = row.createCell(2);
    cell.setCellValue(res.getString("datoColuma2"));
    i++;
 }
```

Comment: Gracias!! @Rcordoval, solo una pregunta hay manera de escribir la primera columna de mi consulta de manera horizontal en el excel, el resto de colunmas en vertical?..